# Linq Intersect Comma Delimited String with List Containing Strings Any & All

Tags: c#, regex, linq

In my database there is a field which is a string of ids delimited by commas. (i.e. "5,8,9")  The user will select from a multi drop down that creates a list of selected ids.  I want to search my database (for both All & Any) where the user generated list of ids is a match.

My current attempt is the following.

```
reports = reports.Where(r => r.ItemIds.Split(',').ToList().Intersect(ItemIdsList).Any());
```

and then...

```
reports = reports.Where(r => r.ItemIds.Split(',').ToList().Intersect(ItemIdsList).All());
```

Comment: "In my database there is a field which is a string of ids delimited by commas. (i.e. `'5,8,9'`)" That's unfortunate. You are living with consequences of an extremely poor design choice.

Comment: I realize the design is poor.  The application is from a quick and dirty data dump that does not contain very much data.  If I need to purge the records and create another table I will.  But before I do that I was just curious is this was possible in a linq expression.  Thanks!

Comment: If there is very little data in these tables, you could replace `report` with `report.AsEnumerable()` in your queries, and they should work.

Comment: You either have to get all the data and the filter in VS or write a function in the database to perform the split and search.  See following webpage : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

Comment: i rewrote the query as follows reports = reports.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.ItemIds.Split(',').ToList().Intersect(ItemIdsList).All());  and I got a NullReferenceException

Comment: @RobS `All` requires a predicate so I don't know how you got that to even compile.

Comment: I'm working on the Any() right now.  All() is the next step.  Any() will compile but I get the runtime error.

Comment: I found a single null value in the data that was causing it to error.  I added AsEnumerable() to the expression as stated by dasblinkenlight and it worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if all values are distinct, i.e. there are no duplicates in ItemIds and ItemIdsList

```
reports = reports.Where(r => r.ItemIds.Split(',').ToList().Intersect(ItemIdsList).Count() > 0); // instead of .Any()  
reports = reports.Where(r => r.ItemIds.Split(',').ToList().Intersect(ItemIdsList).Count() == ItemIdsList.Count()); // instead of .All()
```